# Shape of Fan Blades

Tags: classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics

How is the shape of the blades of an air fan determined? Trial and error, or is there a theory behind it? What are they trying to maximize, volume of air dislocated per rotation?

Comment: I guess a follow up question is how do you measure the amount of air that is dislocated.

Comment: More on fans: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9030/2451

Comment: +1 for using the `Engineering` tag. Got to support my kind :-)

Comment: 'Dyson' make a blade-less fan. No idea how it works though :P

Comment: @qftme - there is a fan in base and then a series of angled holes in the ring shaped part that blow the air toward you. The clever part is that this high speed air drags more room air through the loop in the middle so gives you much more flow than the small hidden fan alone

Comment: @Martin - Very interesting, thanks. I wonder whether the same principle work for a water pump? I suspect one would require near-lamina flow from the internal pump to holes but have no idea if this is feasible..

Comment: @qftime - I think you need a compressible fluid for a venturi effect. You do use a similar system in chemistry labs with flowing water 'dragging' air to make a vacuum pump http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venturi_pump

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mostly trial and error - but in a computer.

A combination of [Computational Fluid Dynamics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_fluid_dynamics) (modelling how the air flows over the blade) and [Finite Element Modelling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_element_method) (how the stresses in the metal behave)

Both of these are complex areas - and when they come to together you need a lot of expensive computers and some even more expensive engineers.

Comment: Maybe you also want to add http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blade_element_theory , which is basically a subset of the computational methods you are referring to, but still often used.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess the Lift/Drag ratio of the blades is important. Lift = wind thrust (and speed), and Drag = friction and power loss.

Since the part of the blade moves slower the closer to the center, the angle of attack needs to increase to provide the same wind speed. Keeping an even velocity profile is probably important in order to minimize losses due to turbulence.

There is probably a lot to be done with the wing-tips that is *not* done due to aesthetic reasons. pffft.